# How does ImageList.ImageCollection handle duplicates?

Tags: c#, .net

In C# .NET, how does [`ImageList.ImageCollection.Add(String,Image)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1h1kxkbx%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) handle duplicate keys? Will it overwrite entries with the same key, or throw/no-op? MSDN documentation on this function is bare and does not mention the behavior in this respect.

Comment: Why don't you try it? It will probably be faster than to wait for an answer...

Comment: Also funny: "The key comparison is not case-sensitive" in RemoveByKey() http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.imagelist.imagecollection.removebykey(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @ThomasLevesque I didn't mention that getting a quick answer was important. If you didn't know lions attacked humans, would you go poke one with a stick to find out? Your comment is silly and completely unhelpful.

Comment: @RobertDailey, how is that related? Are you risking your life by taking 5 minutes to write a small test program? I'm just suggesting that sometimes you can easily find the answer on your own...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've looked through the source of `ImageList.ImageCollection` and I can't see any duplicate-key checking code.

Internally, `ImageCollection` uses an `ArrayList` of `ImageInfo` classes to store keys (`ImageInfo` contains a string `Key` field). Its operations are actually inefficient as it isn't a hashtable, instead string lookups are performed by iterating through each stored `ImageInfo` in the ArrayList and returning the index of the first match (i.e. O(n) search), se `ImageList.ImageCollection.IndexOfKey`. thus adding a second image with the same key will cause that image to be inaccessible by key, however it will still be accessible by index.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code in Reflector, it internally uses an ArrayList for storing the keys, so when you access an image by key, it's going to return the first item that was added with that key.

Comment: +1 for mentioning Reflector, I will use this tool in the future!